# how to display images in cx_freeze

Tags: python, pyqt4, cx-freeze

I have a pyqt4 program that have an icon for `MainWindow`(a `QMainWindow` instance). This window also have one more image both these are with (.PNG) extension. It is displaying the image when I run it with python shell. But when I build it using CX_FREEZE, it is not showing any image in exe. I am unable to tackle the problem.
Any help  would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an `imageformats` directory anywhere in your build directory? Qt needs plugins to read certain image formats, but cx_Freeze should automatically include those if you're using QtGui. If you're not already on the latest version of cx_Freeze, try upgrading.

Comment: yes.i am using QTGui also the Build forlder that is created exibits imageformats folder but still i am getting the problem.@ThomasK

Comment: Are you using [Qt resource system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html) to pack the images within the application?

Comment: No i am not using that.i have resolved the issue.i was placing the images in the wrong folder

Comment: Using resource system helps with that kind of issues, consider trying it for embedding files in your application.